# How can I restrict the width of an HtmlTable column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to reduce the width of an HTMLTable column, and have text content within it wrap.

Everything I've tried to set the width and force the text to wrap has failed. Here's the html:

```
<td width="40" class="skybluebackground centertext"><label class="wrappable"><strong>Total Expenses</strong></label></td>
```

...other rows have cells like this in that column (number input elements):

```
<td width="40"><input width="40" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" 
name="airfareTotalExpense" id="airfareTotalExpense"/></td>
```

Trying to reduce the width of those number input elements fails, too.

The CSS I've tried:

```
.wrappable {
  width: 10em;
}
```

I tried setting several other properties, too, but obviously nothing worked.

I also tried this:

**Total Expenses**

With this CSS:

td.wrappable {
  width: 5em;
}

...but that doesn't work, either - the column remains too wide for my purposes, and thus the text doesn't wrap.

I also tried this on the HtmlTable:

```
 <COLGROUP WIDTH="48"></COLGROUP>
 <COLGROUP WIDTH="32"></COLGROUP>
 . . .
```

...but it has no effect, either.

Setting column widths on HTMLTables can't be that hard; what am I missing here?

Comment: There is a trailing `</pre>` in your html, first example.  Are you sure your table DOM validates?

Comment: That was a bogus/superfluous preserving of the preserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label is an inline element so width being set doesn't work. Change it to `block` or `inline-block`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvOwNJ

```
.wrappable {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```